# JQuery sortable moving rows having different heights

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I got a table with 3 rows on which I enable sorting like this:

```js
 
 $('#table').sortable( {
           items: '> tbody > tr',
           handle: 'td:not(.no-drag)',
           cursor: 'pointer',
           cancel: '.no-drag',
           axis: 'y',
           dropOnEmpty: false,
              
           start: function (e, ui) {

              ui.item.find('table').hide();
              ui.item.height('auto');
              $(ui.placeholder[0]).height('auto');                    
           },

           stop: function (ev, ui) {
                    ui.item.find('table').show();
                }
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table id='table'>
<tbody>
       <tr id='row0'>
           <td> 
              <div>row0</div>
              <table>
                     <tr><td>sub1</td></tr>
                     <tr><td>sub2</td></tr>
                     <tr><td>sub3</td></tr>
                     <tr><td>sub4</td></tr>
                     <tr><td>sub5</td></tr>
                     <tr><td>sub6</td></tr>
                     <tr><td>sub7</td></tr>
                     <tr><td>sub8</td></tr>
                     <tr><td>sub9</td></tr>
                     <tr><td>sub10</td></tr>
               </table>
           </td></tr>
       <tr id='row1'><td>row 1</td></tr>
       <tr id='row2'><td>row 2</td></tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

The first time i click on #row0 and try to move it to be the last item or between #row1 and #row2 the placeholder does not show and the drop cannot be performed.

The problem get worse the more elements you have (since moving up or down top the top or bottom with dozens of elements is tedious)

A workaround is to click #row0 and move it all the way up or all the way down (or way up and down enough based on the height of the ui helper element), at that point the actual height of the helper element is probably recalculated and the placeholders start to show correctly.

This problem is related to the height of the element being moved and it's ui-sortable-helper height, i suppose.

I tried to use the 'helper' function and set the height before starting to drag around like this:

```
helper: function(e,item){ return item.height(30); }
```

or like this:

```
helper: function(e,item){
    item.find('table').hide();
    item.height('auto');
    return item; 
}
```

But the first time i drag i still need to go down the original height of the table (the height #row0 is before collapsing the inner table)

Any way to fix this?

Comment: This line, `if ($(this).closest("table").attr('id') != '@Model.TableId')` has a lot of issues. `this` is the row, and then you find a child table. Yet none of your child tables have an ID attribute. That suggests that this statement will always be `true`. In addition to that, we cannot replicate the issue is we cannot know what `@Model.TableId` is.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, that's aspnet specific stuff: we atually dynamically generate ui based on models. i'll remove that bit

Comment: .closest traverses up through its ancestors, not children btw

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#table').sortable({
    items: '> tbody > tr',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    cancel: '.no-drag',
    axis: 'y',
    dropOnEmpty: false,
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    helper: function(evt, el) {
      if ($(el).find("table").length) {
        $(el).find("table").hide();
        $(el).find("td").append("<span>[===]</span>");
      }
      return el;
    },
    tolerance: "pointer",
    stop: function(ev, ui) {
      ui.item.find("span").remove();
      ui.item.find('table').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-sortable tr {
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.ui-state-highlight {
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table id='table'>
  <tr id='row0'>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>sub1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sub2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sub3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sub4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sub5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sub6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sub7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sub8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sub9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sub10</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='row1'>
    <td>row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='row2'>
    <td>row 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This hides the table and gives the row some content for the User to identify as reference for the item they are moving. Once dropped, it is reverted back.

**Alternate**

```js
$(function() {
  function shrinkRow(event, el) {
    $(el).find("table").hide();
    $(el).find("td").append("<span>[===]</span>");
    $(el).position({
      my: "center",
      at: "center",
      of: event
    });
  }

  function unshrinkRow(el) {
    $(el).css({
      top: "",
      left: ""
    });
    $(el).find("span").remove();
    $(el).find('table').show();
  }

  $('#table').sortable({
    items: '> tbody > tr',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    cancel: '.no-drag',
    axis: 'y',
    dropOnEmpty: false,
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    //tolerance: "pointer",
    start: function(e, ui) {
      if (ui.item.find("table").length) {
        shrinkRow(e, ui.item);
      }
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      if (ui.item.find("table").length) {
        unshrinkRow(ui.item);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-sortable tr {
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.ui-state-highlight {
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table id='table'>
  <tr id='row0'>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>sub1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sub2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sub3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sub4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sub5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sub6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sub7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sub8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sub9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sub10</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='row1'>
    <td>row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='row2'>
    <td>row 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This has largely the same effect yet it does seem to work a bit better. Depending on which part of the sub-table is clicked up, that initially is the tolerance point. if you click on `sub1` versus `sub5`, you will see the difference.

I tried fixing this by setting the position of the element to that of the event to help correct the offset of the original height. It does seem to improve it a bit yet nothing seem to overcome the very initial issue.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the asnwer. unfortunately this shows the same misbehavior i'm asking support for: the first time you click on the table containing the sub and move the mouse down you can't directly drop the element between row1 and row2: you need to go up and down with the mouse a couple of times and then the placeholder starts to show correctly and the drop can succeed. This is the problem i'm talking about, it's not easy to explain but it's there. Any further help appreciated.

Comment: @MauroSampietro I edited my code to help clarify. With the Placeholder, you can see that it does initially sort, yet it's working from the initial height of the row. It seems to catch up after some movement, yet that's not very acceptable. Can try changing the height in `start` yet I doubt it will catch the change as the element is already in the Drag event by that time. Might look at binding to `mousedown` so that it's triggered before the mouse move that would trigger drag.

Comment: @MauroSampietro added some alternate code, not much better.